# In SQL, how can I multiple a number by an array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, operation

Basically, I have an array that I need to multiply a number by each element, for example:

```
x float[1,2,3,4,5];
x := x * 10; --of course I get the error here
```

so the output would be:
{10,20,30,40,50}

Comment: As mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49328695/593144) you could to use `unnest()` function. Shorter notation: `x := array(select unnest(x) * 10);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `unnest` -> do calculation -> `array_agg`:

```
SELECT array_agg(unnest * 10)  FROM UNNEST('{1,2,3,4,5}' :: int[])
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=cd2594012f9644e0117b96d2a2eedd8e)**

---

To be sure about order of elements you could add `WITH ORDINALITY`:

```
SELECT array_agg(unnest * 10 ORDER BY ordinality) 
FROM UNNEST('{1,2,3,4,5}' :: int[] )WITH ORDINALITY
```